# How to prevent DDoS Attack from HTTP server written in Go?

Tags: security, http, go, ddos

I'm developing an HTTP server in [Go](http://golang.org/), but it doesn't seem to be able to prevent DDoS attacks. Do I need to implement a firewall for my server?

There's also another solution: I could use Nginx as proxy server to prevent DDoS attacks, but it will complicate server deployment.

Comment: What type of DDoS attacks are you trying to mitigate that Go can't handle?

Comment: Protecting against a full DDoS attack is almost impossible if you ask  me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to implement a firewall for my server?

**OMG YES!**

But it won't help much for DDOS. You need to be able to profile the attack and patch responses quickly for this. Using something like fail2ban make this much easier, but that you weren't sure if you needed a fiewall / if it would help with DDOS suggests that you may easily do more harm than good by trying to build adaptive defences, hence in your case I'd recommend not worrying about a DDOS until you get one / get a good hosting company who can provide network level services if such an attack occurs.

Comment: My opinion is to implement a simple firewall module in my program write by Go, it can make my server refuse any request from clients send them too frequently, also can log any illegal request which might from a cracker. Any third-party defense is not my first choice since it will make server deployment complicate.

Comment: Implementing a firewall at layer 7, that's a novel approach. Not even Microsoft have tried that yet.

Comment: So that means even Microsoft is not fool enough to try this? LOL, I got the point :)

Comment: On that note, you may find it more effective to use a platform-as-a-service (like Google App Engine) in which the infrastructure concerns are handled by professionals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Nginx would be better or worse than your Go server. You still need a real firewall as well.

Comment: Using Nginx for what's designed together with a good firewall and IPS would be the minimal protection at the front-end.  You might consider using Go + Google AppEngine and thus concentrate on your app instead of the network engineering aspects.